# How to delete an element from an array in RTDB without downloading the entire array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, firebase-realtime-database

I have a huge array in the RTDB that contains more than 1600 object, and I want to delete the element of index 100 for example.

I don't want to read the array in, modify it, and write it back out.

I have got a good idea on how to deal with this situation in the Add/Update cases but still lost when it comes to deleting a single element.

I have tried to use `ref.child('100').remove();`, but this is turning the array into an object

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the exact node you need to delete.